# $R_d\cong H^1(X,\mathcal T_X)$ for smooth hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, deformation-theory

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n (n>3)$ be a smooth hypersurface defined by degree $d$ polynomial $F$, and let $R=k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/(\partial F_0,\cdots,\partial F_n)$ be a graded ring (sometimes called Jacobian ring).

I want to prove that:

> $$R_d\cong H^1(X,\mathcal T_X)$$

where $R_d$ is the degree $d$ piece of $R$ and $\mathcal T_X$ is the tangent bundle of $X$.

---

Here is my approach:

I already see there is a short exact sequence 
\begin{equation} 
0\to H^0(\mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}|_X)\to H^0(\mathcal O_X(d))\to H^1(\mathcal T_X)\to 0
\end{equation}

So need to show
$$
 H^0(\mathcal O_X(d))/H^0(\mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}|_X)\cong R_d
$$

But I have no idea why this is true.

---

Here is (a sketch of) how I get the exact sequence:

It comes from the normal bundle sequence:
$$ 0\to \mathcal T_X \to \mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}|_X \to \mathcal N_{X/{\mathbb P^n}}\to 0 $$
and $\mathcal N_{X/{\mathbb P^n}}=\mathcal O(d)$. It induces long exact sequence on cohomology, hence remains to show $H^0(\mathcal T_X)=0$ and $H^1(\mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}|_X)=0$. The second one comes from Euler sequence. For the first one, we note that $X$ is smooth implies $\partial_i F$ forms a regular sequence, and hence $\Sigma h_i  \partial_i F=0$ implies all $h_i=0$. Let $h_i$ be a section of $\mathcal O_X(1)$, we can extend it to $\mathbb P^n$. We still use $h_i$ to denote the extension. $h_i$ lies in $H^0(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O(1))$ hence is a linear polynomial. And $\Sigma h_i  \partial_i F$ vanishes on $X$ means $\Sigma h_i  \partial_i F \in (F)$ hence we can assume $\Sigma h_i  \partial_i F=\Sigma x_i  \partial_i F$. By $\partial_i F$ forms a regular sequence we conclude $h_i=x_i$. Therefore, any global section of $\mathcal O_X(1)^{n+1}$which has no contribution to the normal direction of $X$ also has no contribution to the tangent direction of $\mathbb P^n$ (hence also no contribution to tangent direction of $X$). Remains to see if any section of $\mathcal T_X$ can be extended to $\mathcal O_X(1)^{n+1}$, which can be done by Euler sequence.

Comment: Can you identify the composite map $\mathcal{O}_X(1)^{n+1}\to \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^n}|X\to \mathcal{O}_X(d)$ as the derivatives you are looking for? Also, your $R$ should be $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ and you should have $\partial F/\partial x_0$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, I can see that geometrically the composition is projection to the normal direction.

Comment: If you can, you should be able to finish the argument.

Comment: @Mohan Yeah I edited it. But I still didn't see why it is true... although I can feel it is very close to.

Comment: @Mohan Could you explain why $H^0(\mathcal O_X(d))/H^0(\mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}|_X)\cong R_d$? My problem is, I think we need $H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d))$ here, but I cannot find a good way to relate it to $H^0(\mathcal O_X(d))$.

Comment: There is a natural surjection $H^0(O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d))\to H^0(O_X(d))$ and the kernel is just the one-dimensional vector space generated by $F$.